# Apply animation on image in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want help to apply [this animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T051c.gif) using flutter
when moving to the first element of the horizontal list its image extend its size and take the full background and when moving to another element this image shrink to appear as a first element in the horizontal list.

thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you want from that animation? Please be a bit more specific.

Comment: when moving to the first element of the horizontal list its image extend its size and take the full background and when moving to another element this image shrink to appear as a first element in the horizontal list.

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far.

Comment: So the title My Schedule is the first element?

Comment: Or do you mean the image with the towers (and the button "Explore") is the first item in the list?

Comment: this first element is the image with towers and explore button. when moving to this element the image takes the full screen background otherwise the image appear as a part of the horizontal list with the same other cards element size.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.